# SSH No Longer Working After Sierra Update

Tags: network, ssh

I'm trying to ssh into a remote server using the format:

```
user@ip -i ~/.ssh/path/to/key
```

and I get the following error:

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 55: Bad configuration option: gssapikeyexchange
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 56: Bad configuration option: gssapitrustdns
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 2 bad configuration options
```

Connecting to a server without an SSH key doesn't work either.

Thanks.

Comment: What do the relevant lines look like in your ssh_config?

Comment: @dr.nixon     GSSAPIKeyExchange no
    GSSAPITrustDNS no

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46454141/32453 if you want an option that works *with gssapitrustdns still enabled* :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comment out or remove the lines

```
gssapikeyexchange no
gssapitrustdns no
```

from your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and you should be good.

Comment: What are the consequences?

Comment: Since the new version does not support these options, the only consequence is that it will start to work. Otherwise you will not be able to @MaxRied use kerberos key exchange, which the OP was most probably not using.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use Kerberos (and hence the `gssapi*` options) a viable option is to copy an `ssh` executable from an older Mac (any version <= OpenSSH_6.7) should work.

```
cp my-older-ssh /usr/local/bin/ssh
```