# macOS Sierra broke SSH Kerberos authentication

Tags: terminal, ssh, macos, kerberos

I have used Kerberos GSSAPI authentication together with SSH to connect from my Mac to work servers. However, ever since the macOS Sierra upgrade, I'm forced to enter passwords again.

My `~/.ssh/config` looks like this:

```
Host MYSERVER
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
```

I originally had there `GSSAPITrustDns yes` as well, but after the Sierra upgrade, SSH refused to start up saying that it could not parse the config. Removing the line fixed that.

Is there any way to get this working again?

Comment: Is there anything suspicious in the verbose output?

Comment: I found this in `-vvv` output. See for yourself: http://pastebin.com/WPcRba7d

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't provide any help on that. But this `Server (MYSERVER) unknown` looks somewhat suspicious.

Comment: It does not look like complete log. Removing the `GSSAPITrustDns` makes some difference according to the documentation. How do you connect to the server? Do you use whole hostname?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the hostname (e.g. remote.server.com)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634166/after-update-mac-os-sierra-can-not-use-ssh-login-remote-system-how-can-i-fix-th FWIW

Comment: @rogerdpack That's not helping. It suggests disabling GSSAPI if you don't use Kerberos. But I *do* use it and need it to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH No Longer Working After Sierra Update](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255419/ssh-no-longer-working-after-sierra-update)

Comment: @PetrMánek Well, it also suggested copying a binary from a 10.11 OS :) I added an answer there on how to build your own with the patches just recently as well, FWIW. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

I asked this in the SSH mailing list openssh-unix-dev@mindrot.org and I got this answer:

> The GSSAPITrustDNS was never part of [portable OpenSSH](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=trustdns). This option originally comes from [third party](http://www.sxw.org.uk/computing/patches/openssh.html) extending kerberos support in OpenSSH, which is no longer maintained, but can be simply rebased on the current sources.
>
> The problem in this case is Apple dropping this patch used by many people, so the Apple is the place where you should ask (or your OpenSSH packager of your favorite repository).

http://marc.info/?l=openssh-unix-dev&m=147850754710753&w=2

It seems that we have to ask apple to put this feature back.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually quite helpful. So, what's in your opinion the best way to get Apple involved? RADAR or some of their customer / dev forums?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I did not see your message. I did use a forum in here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7738793 but apparently we cannot contact apple from there, it is just a user to user thing. As the others say we can file a bug report. However I haven't done it yet, I have been lazy and busy. Some one else can do it and share the results here.

Comment: Or install your own copy of openssh https://stackoverflow.com/a/46454141/32453

Answer (score 1):

Apparently apple used to apply some GSSAPI patches to their openssh version, but have recently stopped doing it.  Fix: build your own with the patches: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46454141/32453

Answer (score -1):

DSA Keys are not secure anymore and you need replace them with RSA keys.

Generate new RSA Keys

> ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"

You can refer more detailed steps here

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Comment: I'm aware of that. However, afaik Kerberos tickets do not use DSA.